# Is there a way to draw the symbol for "y root of x" the same way it appears in the Windows Calculator?

Tags: java, swing, unicode

I have looked at the Windows Calculator, and I have seen that, in the scientific mode, there is a button that reads "y root of x", as shown here:

[image: Click me!]

I'm looking to replicate the way this button looks like in my own Swing project. Is there a way to do so? I have looked at Unicode characters, and there is none for this particular symbol.

Comment: Did you try drawing a *y*, *√* and *x* in the appropriate places?

Comment: I have. The symbols don't appear the way they show up in the calculator, however.

Comment: Then you didn't draw them in the appropriate places.

Comment: I've you've tried it, why does the question not mention this?

Comment: `calc.exe` doesn't use text characters for most of its buttons.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such character. What you can do is to create an image and afix it to your button just like you would a text.

Answer (score 1):

The font used for most of the Calculator buttons is `Segoe UI`. For the half-dozen or so non-Unicode characters, including "y root", Calculator uses characters from the Private Use Area of `Segoe UI Symbol`